# Extend SharePoint 2013 Search

Tags: 2013, search

I want to extend the search results when I am searching sites. My Query is WebTemplate:MySiteDefinition and it results is like in the following picture

[image]

By the other hand, I have a timer job that calculates in a list the number of documents created or modified in the past 15 days.

Now, what I need to do is that these results became something like this:
[image]

As you can see, I need the title, logo description of the page (these 3 fields no problem to customize), last documents, pending tasks and  an icon that creates an entry in CustomFavourites list in each My Site.
The problem comes here. How can I modify the behaviour of the Search Results WebPart to have my desired look and feel?.

Which will be the best approach? Making a WebPart that inherits from CoreResultsWebPart, ContentBySearchWebPart? I am stucked on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this in the 2013 Enterprise Search Center you can do all this with a display template. You will probably have to use JQuery to perform the secondary lookup to your custom list.

Comment: I am trying the display template approach but it is being hard. Thanks for your answer. I will post the whole solution when I finished

Answer (score 1):

Download the display template and customize it as per your needs. Add the columns you want the search to display in the display template and upload it.